# Chrome saying "cannot read property of undefined"...even though it does

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-chrome, object, undefined

Have no idea what's going on.

Taking objects from $.ajax success msg, storing them in new array to pass to plugin, plugin uses the data yet reports cannot use property 'ID' in my title above.

Stops at end of for loop and points to first line of for loop in console.  It clones with the data and everything.  Nothing after the for works.

**Snippet in $.ajax()**

```
var suppliers = [];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    suppliers[i] = msg.d[i];
}
$.fn.appendSnapshots(suppliers);
```

**Where it fails**

```
$.fn.appendSnapshots = function(snapshots) {
var accumulatedHeight = $("#suppliersTable").height();
var IDsShowing = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<snapshots.length; i++){

    if($("#supplierStatusDataRow\\." + snapshots[i].ID).length == 0){

        var $supplierStatusDataRow = $("#supplierStatusDataRow").clone(false)
        $supplierStatusDataRow.css('z-index', 1);
        $supplierStatusDataRow.find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function() { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "." + snapshots[i].ID); });

        $("#supplierStatusDataDiv").append($supplierStatusDataRow);

        $("#statusSupplierName\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].SupplierName);
        $("#statusSupplierNumber\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].SupplierNumber);
        $("#statusHostNumber\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].HostNumber);
        $("#statusSupplierType\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].SupplierType);
        $("#statusRecievedReportStatus\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].RecievedReportStatus);
        $("#statusBarCode\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].BarCode);
        $("#statusNumberOfUsers\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].NumberOfUsers);
        $("#statusOnBoardStatus\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].OnBoardStatus);
        $("#statusSupplierEmail\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].SupplierEmail);
        $("#statusPrimaryBuyer\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].PrimaryBuyer);
        $("#statusLastPODate\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].LastPODate);
        $("#statusPOMTD\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].POMTD);
        $("#statusPOYTD\\." + snapshots[i].ID).append(snapshots[i].POYTD);

        $supplierStatusDataRow.css('top', accumulatedHeight);

        $supplierStatusDataRow.animate({opacity: 1}, 500);

        }
        else{
            $("#supplierStatusDataRow\\." + snapshots[i].ID).animate({top: accumulatedHeight}, 500);
        }

        IDsShowing.push(parseInt(snapshots[i].ID));
        accumulatedHeight += $("#supplierStatusDataRow\\." + snapshots[i].ID).height() - 1;

    }

        $("#supplierStatusDataDiv").find('[id^="supplierStatusDataRow\\."]').each(function(i){ 
        var splitID = $(this).attr("id").split(".");
        if($.inArray(parseInt(splitID[1]), IDsShowing) == -1){
                $("#supplierStatusDataDiv").find('[id^="supplierStatusDataRow\\.' + splitID[1] + '"]').animate(
                    {opacity: 0}, 
                    500, 
                    function() { $("#supplierStatusDataRow\\." + splitID[1]).remove();
                });
            }
        });

        totalHeight = $("#supplierStatusRadioDiv").height() + $("#supplierStatusNameDiv").height() + $("#supplierStatusSlider").height() + accumulatedHeight;
        $("#suppliersSnapshot").animate({height: totalHeight}, 500);
        $("#supplierStatusDataDiv").animate({height: accumulatedHeight}, 500);
    }
```

Comment: what does the msg var looks like? can you do console logafterthe succesful call?

Comment: May not help, but I suggest assigning `snapshots[i]` and `snaphots[i].ID` to variables at the top of the loop. It will make it more readable, and avoid potential typos when writing that expresion each over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking past the end of the array in your `for` loop. Try:

```
for(var i=0; i< msg.d.length; i++){
    suppliers[i] = msg.d[i];
}
```

Comment: it's always the little things, isn't it?  jeez, so stupid.  Thank-you very much!

Comment: you gave a good description of the issue , so it was relatively easy to deduce probable issue. Many others just write "this doesn't work, why"